# What word describes the ability or capacity of oneself on a given day

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that describes one's ability to accomplish a task on the present day, as in a athlete's *daily fitness*, which is what google translate offered me when I tried to translate the word that we have for this in Swedish (which is *dagsform*).

In other words, I am looking for a word or phrase that describes a particular person's ability on the current day that is broad enough to relate to any given task.

An example of a sentence could be *I am sorry for coming up short, my [insert word] is not at its best*.

Comment: More idiomatic in English would be: I'm not at my best today. Not a direct translation, though.

Comment: ... or: I'm not at the top of my game

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, that works for that particular sentence. I wonder if there might be a word that one could use more generally and also relate to specifically.

Comment: yes, I know, we have the same word in Danish (and Norwegian) but unfortunately not all words have translations. By the way, in Danish, one can also use the word in e.g. reviews of restaurants: I visited the restaurant to test their [dagsform] (i.e. whether they could deliver their usual standard).

Comment: I can think of no single word that means *daily ability* or *current ability*.

Comment: A common *expression* is something like: *(I've got a cold.) I'm only [working / performing / functioning] at 75% today.*

Comment: _fitness_ is probably the word you're looking for.  For restaurants English might use the word _suitability_.

Comment: I’m not at peak performance/capacity today.  I’m not at my peak today.  I’m a little off-peak today.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google translate, the Swedish word *dagsform* loosely translate to the compound word "*daily form*".

A single word for *daily form* would be just "***form***", which in sports means a physical state or condition or mood of a player on a given day or in particular time frame or state starting from certain time.

Usage: If you want to use this word for a particular day or certain time frame, then you have to indicate explicitly "today" or "particular time-frame" or "start time" in the given sentence. Check Oxford examples below.

Please check Oxford dictionary *[entry 8.2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/form)* for the word ***form.***

> **A person's mood and state of health.**
>
> > "That morning Christine had been on great ***form*** but at 8pm her mood changed dramatically."
> >
> > "And then yesterday I retired to my sickbed, feeling decidedly under the weather, and am still not on top ***form*** today."

Synonyms: *state of health*, *physical state*, *condition*, *constitution*.

Answer (score -1):

*fitness* is the common American term.  From Google's dictionary: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=define+fitness

> fit·ness /ˈfitnəs/ noun noun: fitness
>
> - the condition of being physically fit and healthy.   "disease and lack
>   of fitness are closely related"
>
> synonyms: health, strength, robustness, sturdiness, hardiness, vigor, lustiness, stalwartness, athleticism, toughness, ruggedness, physical fitness, muscularity, tone, good health, good condition, good shape, well-being, state of health, condition, shape, trim, fettle;
>
> informal huskiness, nick
>
> "polo requires tremendous fitness"
>
> antonyms: unfitness
>
> - the quality of being suitable to fulfill a particular role or task.
>
> "he had a year in which to establish his fitness for the office."
>
> synonyms:  suitability, capability, competence, competency, proficiency, ability, aptitude, readiness, preparedness, qualification, eligibility, worthiness, appropriateness, appropriacy, adequacy.
>
> "he was called before medical boards to assess his fitness for active service"
>
> antonyms:  unfitness, unsuitability
>
> #### Biology
>
> - an organism's ability to survive and reproduce in a particular environment.
>
> plural noun: fitnesses
>
> "if sharp teeth increase fitness, then genes causing teeth to be sharp will increase in frequency"

Comment: Also note that fitness can also be used for daily ups and downs--e.g., I am unfit today today because I drank too much last night.

Comment: This doesn't cover the "daily" nature of the request.